# Do not submit form after wrong code

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am working on a WordPress plugin which adds an auth code to the login form.

This is the process of checking if the auth code is valid:

```
add_action( 'wp_authenticate', 'authcode_check', 5 );
function authcode_check($username) {
    $options = get_option( 'authcode_settings' );
    if(!empty($options['code'])) {
        global $wpdb;

        if ( !username_exists( $username ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $set_code = $options['code'];
        $submit_code = $_POST['auth_key'];

        if(empty($submit_code)) {
            add_filter( 'login_errors', function( $error ) {$error = '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Authentication code cannot be empty.';return $error;} );
            return;
        } elseif ( ! ( $set_code == $submit_code ) ) {
            add_filter( 'login_errors', function( $error ) {$error = '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Authentication code is invalid.';return $error;} );
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is; when the user enters their WordPress name and password correctly, but not the auth code, the form still submits and log the user in.

I tried `return false` but that didn't work.

Is there any way to prevent the form from logging the user in when they have entered a wrong auth code?

Comment: Are they entering a bad auth code or not entering an auth code?  In your code, the return false is only for the former...

Comment: Also, `! ( $set_code == $submit_code )` is a very odd way of writing `$set_code != $submit_code`

Comment: @Devon It should not submit for both the bad auth code and empty auth code and just display the error. Currently, it logs the user in.

Comment: @Devon Adding `return false` to the top of the code didn't work out, I've added the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working Example

*Updated after chat with @J.Doe*

We can hook into the `login_form` hook, to display the input for the *authentication code*:

```
/**
 * 'Authentication Code' Input
 */
add_action( 'login_form', function() 
{
    // Fetch the stored code
    $options = get_option( 'authcode_settings' );

    // Display code input
    if( isset( $options['code'] ) ) 
        printf(
           '<p class="login-authenticate">
            <label for="auth_key">%s</label>
            <input type="text" name="so38551606_auth_key" id="so38551606_auth_key" 
                   class="input" value="" size="20" autocomplete="off" />
            </p>',
            esc_html__( 'Authentication Code', 'mydomain' )
        );
} );
```

You can hook into the `authenticate` filter, within the `wp_authenticate()` function, for the validating part:

```
/**
 * Validate 'Authentication Code' Input
 */
add_filter( 'authenticate', function( $user )
{
    // Fetch stored code value
    $options = get_option( 'authcode_settings' );

    // Nothing to do if there's no stored code value
    if( ! isset( $options['code'] ) )
        return $user;

    // Fetch the user's code input
    $submit_code = isset( $_POST['so38551606_auth_key'] ) 
        ? $_POST['so38551606_auth_key'] 
        : null;

    // Validation's logic       
    $is_valid_auth_code = ! is_null( $submit_code ) 
        && ( $options['code'] === $submit_code );

    // Valid auth code  
    if( $is_valid_auth_code )
        return $user;

    // Add an unvalid auth code error
    if( is_wp_error( $user ) )
        $user->add( 
            'invalid_auth_code', 
            sprintf(
            '<strong>%s</strong>: %s',
            esc_html__( 'ERROR', 'mydomain' ),
            esc_html__( 'Authentication code is invalid.', 'mydomain' )
        )
    ); 
    // Create a new auth code error
    else
        $user = new WP_Error(
            'invalid_auth_code', 
            sprintf(
                '<strong>%s</strong>: %s',
                esc_html__( 'ERROR', 'mydomain' ),
                esc_html__( 'Authentication code is invalid.', 'mydomain' )
            )
        ); 

    return $user;
}, 100 );
```

Here we use a priority of `100` because we want to run it after the default callbacks of:

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password',  20, 3 );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_email_password',     20, 3 );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_spam_check',         99    );
```

We prefixed the POST variable with `so38551606_` to avoid possible name collision.

Output example:

[image: auth input key validation example]

Comment: Thank you for your answer; May I ask what you mean with "Modify your needs" and what I need to add to that code?

Comment: What I meant was, to add your own logic to the demo, because currently it  always gives you error message, no matter what you type in ;-) @J.Doe

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure this out myself. I hope to get some support from you, I have this code right now: http://pastebin.com/2gpXsKAj

Comment: There are few problems in your pastebin code, too long to explain in a comment, so I updated the answer with a new example instead @J.Doe

Comment: When applying your examples, this is my result: http://i.imgur.com/VfhqBXQ.png - Should we move to chat to figure this out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118442/discussion-between-j-doe-and-birgire).

Comment: I updated the answer after our chat ps: `login_form` is an *action* @J.Doe

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return false` use `return` as apparently WordPress prefers it that way,  look at the existing username code it just returns, not false, not true, just return
Also place the add filter functions before the return statements as a return signifies that the code stops running at that point,  nothing below it is executed anymore, so your filters won't appear unless you move them

Comment: I don't get how this is possible. I've updated my code in the question, but it still logs me in. I am almost forced to use `exit()` but I don't want to use that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not too familiar with WordPress, but is your function called from within the login function? If so, you need to exit,  else you should add some code from the actual login

Answer (score 0):

Can you prove the user isn't being logged in? Or are you just assuming they are being logged in because the error messages aren't being shown?

Anything after the `return` keyword won't be run. So in your if statements, you have two `return false;`s if the auth key doesn't match and then you are calling a function afterwards. This function won't be run so the error code won't be displayed.

What you can do however, is move the function above the return keyword. It will then display the error and return false.

Comment: I am being redirected to the Wordpress dashboard after entering a wrong authentication code, so I'm pretty sure I am being logged in at that point, I will try your suggestions.